# A point E is taken on the side $AC$ of triangle $ABC$. through $E$ pass straight lines $DE$ and $EF$ parallel to , . . .

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

A point E is taken on the side $AC$ of triangle $ABC$. Through $E$ pass straight lines $DE$ and $EF$ parallel to sides $BC$ and $AB$ respectively.

prove that $S_{BDEF} = 2 \sqrt {S_{ADE} \cdot S_{EFC}}$

On reading the solution to this problem, the author noted that

$\frac {S_{BDEG}} {2S_{ADE}} = \frac {S_{BDE}} {S_{ADE}}$

But I don't understand how he obtained this result as I have tried to reproduce it for hours but failed.

Comment: Connect $E$ and $B$ with a line $BE$. Note that $S_{BDE}=S_{BEF}$  since $BDEF$ is a parallelogram.

Comment: @Hamed I did that already but couldn't obtain any reasonable result from it.

Comment: I'm confused, so you proved $S_{BDEF}/2S_{ADE}=S_{BDE}/S_{ADE}$? But the way you formulated the question, this seems to be the problem! So do you want to prove this equality or do you want to know how can one use it to prove the theorem?

Comment: What is $G$ by the way? You never define what $G$ is.

Comment: @Hamed I want to prove the equality as I'm confused as to how the author came up with it, also, I edited my post, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Triangles $AED$ and $BED$ share the same base $ED$, so their areas are proportional to their altitudes with respect to $ED$, and these in turn are proportional to $AE$ and $EC$ by similar triangles:
$$
{S_{ADE}\over S_{BDE}}={2S_{ADE}\over S_{BDEF}}={AE\over EC}.
$$
With an analogous reasoning one also finds:
$$
{S_{ECF}\over S_{BEF}}={2S_{ECF}\over S_{BDEF}}={EC\over AE}.
$$
By multiplying these equalities one gets:
$$
{4S_{ECF}S_{ADE}\over S_{BDEF}^2}=1,
$$
which is equivalent to what was to be proven.